# Inject service in Attribute with SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, simple-injector

I want to have access into my `DbContext` from factory service to use it in parameterless `[Auth]` in Controllers. I use Simple Injector for DI.

Current Attribure class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    bool Active = true;

    public AuthAttribute()
    {
    }

    public AuthAttribute(bool active)
    {
        Active = active;
    }

    private readonly IMyContextFactory _contextFactory;

    public AuthAttribute(IMyContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!Active)
        {
            return;
        }

        // TODO: Use INITIALIZED IMyContextFactory...
        //var dbContext = _contextFactory.GetContext();
        var dbContext = (MyContext) filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(MyContext));
    }
}
```

My current registration in SI:

`_container.Register<AuthAttribute>(() => new AuthAttribute(_container.GetInstance<IMyContextFactory>()), Lifestyle.Scoped);`

Current issue: both `dbContext` is null - `_contextFactory` is null, and there is no service in `filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices`

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2014/dependency-injection-in-attributes-dont-do-it/

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I updated my post. Both `dbContext` is null